# What's the meaning of third parameter, namely "values" to tf.variable_scope()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

In the description of tf.variable_scope() as the following link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope

For the third parameter, the explanation is just as follows:
values: The list of Tensor arguments that are passed to the op function.

However no given example emphasizes at this regard. So I just wonder could anyone give an further clarification of how to take advantage of the "values" parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Earlier in the documentation it says "This context manager validates that the (optional) values are from the same graph". That parameter contains the values that will be validated.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. I also read it. The problem is due to my limited experience in TensorFlow, such a description is sort of superficial. I cannot image the situation why such a validation is necessary. I thought it's used to organize the name hierarchy of newly created variables, so why it bothers to validate the existing ones. Does it modify the scope of the values passed in? However, thanks very much for your help.